# dialog box is not scrolling in case of long content

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-ui-dialog, cordova-3

I am working on the phonegap project.
I uses 
 codova version 3.5.0
 jquery mobile version 1.2.1

I have made dialog box with back and ok button using data-role = dialog. It is working fine when content is small. But the dialog box is not scrolling when the content is long.
I have attached images of my problem.

I have set "DisallowOverscroll" to "true" in my config.xml file.

`<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />`[image: Dialog box is not scrolling.]

[image: Dialog box is working fine with small length content]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this problem is cordova related, your css should handle overflows. That popup is inside a webkit browser in principle right? Your index.html (or whatever main html is) may fit inside the screen but that web page or any popup inside it can have scrolling. In short, you can check for overflow-y and scrolling with css in general.

Comment: Hi @mentat I have tried the css as u mentioned in your answer.But it did not work.. :(